# Создание нескольких файлов

Tags: c#

Как осуществить проверку на существование файла.

Comment: [File.Exists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать вот этот код, а так в https://docs.microsoft.com есть все ответы на вопросы начинающих.

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Folder";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path); // создание папки если отсутствует
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(path + @"\filename" + i + ".txt")) // проверка наличия файла 
                {
                    File.Create(path + @"\filename" + i + ".txt"); // создания файла с итерацией 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `File.Create` возвращает **открытый** объект `FileStream`. Так как он далее не используется, хорошо бы его сразу закрыть (`Close` или `Dispose`) для предотвращения утечки ресурсов.